# Playing local video in WebView on Android

Tags: android, html, video, webview, local

I'm building an app with a `WebView` thats supposed to play a video, that's saved locally. Strangely the video player is not working with local video files. It does play videos saved on a server though.

The local files (html and video) are saved in a folder `assets/html_test`

Here are the files.

**HTML**

```
<div class="video-container">
  <p>Server</p>
  <video poster="video/star.png" controls>
    <source src="http://broken-links.com/tests/media/BigBuck.m4v" />
  </video>
</div>

<div class="video-container">
  <p>local</p>
  <video poster="video/star.png" controls>
    <source src="BigBuck.m4v" />
  </video>
</div>
```

**onCreate in Activity**

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.browser);

WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND);
webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);

browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html_test/video.html");
```

The first video works, the second one doesn't. I tried different values for the `source`, neither of them worked for me:

```
<source src="BigBuck.m4v" />
<source src="file:///android_asset/html_test/BigBuck.m4v" />
```

Not sure if this is related, but as soon as I press play, `logcat` puts out this:

```
01-07 12:19:18.073: E/MediaPlayer(32542): error (1, -2147483648)
01-07 12:19:18.073: E/MediaPlayer(32542): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

I have no clue what the problem is here. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think it should be `file://` and not `file:///`, just confirm about that.

Comment: This error is generally seen because the format of the file you are playing is not supported on Android.

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

OR: A permission problem? See if this helps : http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2988

Comment: @taymless Can you try with `<embed>` instead of `<video>` in your html?

Comment: @taymless can you tell me how did you solve ur problem..i am having same problem .i want to display video which is store on assets folder..reply soon please

Comment: @swapniladsure take a look at the answer I posted and accepted. You have to enable file access to the video file. I copied the file to the external storage, including all HTML assets. It's all explained below...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slartibartfasts helped me solve this. Since it's just a comment, I'll have to post it myself.

Essentially it's a permission problem. [Here is the link he posted](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=2988). The suggested method for copying files with `MODE_WORLD_READABLE` is deprecated, use the method described in the link below and save the files in the external storage

I had to copy the files to the external storage, and access the video file there. Since the path to the external storage is different within the several versions of android, I copied the all relevant HTML files (including all JS, graphics and video files). See [copying files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4447477/android-how-to-copy-files-in-assets-to-sdcard), scroll down for the answer if you have sub folders.

Here are my copying methods:

```
private void copyAssets(String path)
{
    String[] files = null;

    try
    {
        files = getAssets().list(path);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (files.length == 0)
        copyFile(path);
    else
    {
        File dir = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), path);

        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdir();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
        {
            copyAssets(path + "/" + files[i]);
        }
    }
}

private void copyFile(String filename)
{
    InputStream in = null;

    File file;
    OutputStream out = null;

    try
    {
        in = getAssets().open(filename);
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR WITH in = getAssets().open: " + filename);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    file = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), filename);

    try
    {
        out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "ERROR WITH out = new FileOutputStream(file);");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] data;

    try
    {
        data = new byte[in.available()];

        in.read(data);
        out.write(data);

        in.close();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e1)
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

In my `onCreate` I call

```
copyAssets("matrix");
```

with matrix being the folder in my assets thats holding all files and sub folders.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. I just wanted to verify, your assets were in `file:///android_asset/matrix` in this example?

Comment: Yeah, that's the path the files were in, before I copied them. After that the path from `getExternalFilesDir(null)` will vary depending on the OS version.

Comment: I get a fatal execption:  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError