# Xamarin Android WebView: how to display a content with videos and images html string file in WebView?

Tags: c#, xml, xamarin.android

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqs3L.jpg)                    WebSettings webSettings = HybridView.Settings;
> HybridView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(Context));
> HybridView.SetWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

```
                webSettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                webSettings.AllowFileAccess = true;
                webSettings.LoadsImagesAutomatically = true;
                webSettings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;
                webSettings.SetLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.TextAutosizing);
                webSettings.DomStorageEnabled = true;

                HybridView.ClearCache(true);
                HybridView.Settings.LoadWithOverviewMode = true;
                HybridView.Settings.UseWideViewPort = true;
                HybridView.Settings.BuiltInZoomControls = true;
                HybridView.Settings.DisplayZoomControls = false;

                HybridView.CopyBackForwardList();
                HybridView.CanGoBackOrForward(0);

                string HTMLText = "<html><body>" + "<span style='font-size:150%;' style='color:black;'>" + ContentString + "<span>" + "</body></html>";
                HybridView.LoadData(HTMLText, "text/html", null);
```

Comment: Why is this labeled XML.   XML is not the same as HTML.

Comment: Does the image and video from local folder or remote url ? If just from local storage , here is a working sample you can have a try : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14194890/playing-local-video-in-webview-on-android .

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT Image and video from remote url API. Like this : <div>[beetube-video]https://beetube.live/embed/7LYBZhnLjxZ6A15[/beetube-video]</div><p style=\"text-align:center\"><img alt=\"neymar-jr-biography-net-worth-awards-age-and-many-more-3\" src=\"https://thestreetnews.sgp1.digitaloceanspaces.com/neymar-jr-biography-net-worth-awards-age-and-many-more-3.jpg\" /></p>

Comment: @jdweng Exactly I use Xamarin Android C# with XML file, I try to read the remote url with html string video, text and images and display in WebView. The results I got the images and text, but the video file not display in frame. It just show the video string file 
like this [beetube-video]beetube.live/embed/7LYBZhnLjxZ6A15[/beetube-video] .

Comment: Is video a Mime attachment?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/226004/how-to-play-audiovideo-in-webview-from-memorystrea.html

Comment: Thanks @jdweng I found the solution for that.